# I can't determine the value of diode zener

Tags: diodes, power-electronics, semiconductors

I can't determine the value of this Zener diode. The marking is KD H2.

[image]

Comment: The diode makes up < 5% of your photo. Cropping is generally a good idea.

Comment: Smells like a 1.23V 300mW Zener to me or use any IR LED 300mW type

Comment: You can also replace with 3x parallel 100mW IR LEDs

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5cSvR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Zener test circuit.*

If the Zener is still functional you can test it as shown in Figure 1. Increase V1 while monitoring VM1. VM1 will stop increasing when you've reached the Zener breakdown voltage.